# JSON Schema Validation in PhpStorm

Tags: json, phpstorm, webstorm, jsonschema

I use PhpStorm for much of my development. When I edit my `.jscsrc` file, if I enter something invalid, PhpStorm highlights it and warns me.

[image: See? It shows that it's unknown!]

I have several JSON files that configure various parts of my site for different users/clients. I'd like to have a similar validation be run on my JSON, but I've been unable to track down how this is done.

How can I run a custom JSON schema validator on my JSON files in PhpStorm?

Comment: 1) AFAIK it's hard coded for `.jscsrc` files; 2) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-3536

Comment: Jeeze, that ticket was created in 2010... I guess I won't hold my breath...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON Schemas are available in [PhpStorm 2016.1](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/json-schema.html?page=1). You can map your own schemas on your JSON files and use autocomplete in the editor. Errors are shown as a colored strips when you type.

[image]